# Mask vs delete vertices

Tags: materials, rigging

I'm working on my first character that I want to rig and animate. I created the raw body and added clothes, everything looks fine so far. I want to keep the render time down so should I delete the unseen vertices under the clothes or mask? Will deleting the vertices effect the clothes shape? By that I mean, will the clothes collapse because there is no body underneath? I am, of course, copying the entire character before manipulating but was concerned that any clothes physics would collapse with nothing under it.I'm using Blender 2.8a

Answer (score 0):

if you'll be using cloth physics than yes, the clothes will collapse if you delete vertecies uder clothes, you could delete them if you would rig the clothes as well as part of the character. But I don't think you should worry that much about render times, due to body under clothes. I don't think you would gain much speed by deleting those parts.